# Tomcat uses BASIC auth instead of FORM auth

Tags: java, forms, tomcat, authentication, configuration

I've run into a very weird problem with Tomcat: My Webapp running on Tomcat 6 works just fine with BASIC auth. However I would like to switch to FORM based auth. But when I change my web.xml from:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>my realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

to this here

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/loginfail.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
    <realm-name>my realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Tomcat still uses BASIC auth.

- Both login files exist.
- There are no errors in catalina.err/out.
- Leaving out the realm element makes the browser show "Authentication
  required" instead of the realm name (still uses BASIC)

Are there any conditions under which FORM based auth is not being used?

Comment: Check you haven't configured a BasicAuthenticator valve anywhere.

Comment: Besides one RemoteAddrValve in server.xml I have no Valves defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that reloading the webapp was not enough in my case.

After restarting tomcat by FORM Authentication is being used.

ADD: FORM authentication is using a different digest algorithm than BASIC/DIGEST. Hence my old user auth database is not reusable. But this is a different topic. :)